# Function and loop trouble in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

This program is expecting the user to input a 7-digit number (except 1 and 0), and any digit has a corresponding set of letters
(2=ABC, 3=DEF, 4=GHI, 5=JKL, 6=MNO, 7=PRS, 8=TUV, 9=XYZ, as found on phones in the USA).  Finally, it should output all 2187 possible sequences of letters.

ex: input 2345678
    output should be ADGJMPT ADGJMPU ADGJMPV ADGJMRT ADGJMRU ADGJMRV ADGJMST..........CFILOSV

but my output always is AAAAAAA AAAAAAB AAAAAAC..........CCCCCCC

(I also have trouble in checking number. I first set a loop and array, `if (che[1] != 1 && che[0] != 1) break;` but sometimes it doesn't break.)

Can you explain what's wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int che[50] = { 0 };

    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, i, r, q, number, check;

    char word2[7];

    char word1[8][3] = {
            { 'A', 'B', 'C' },
            { 'D', 'E', 'F' },
            { 'G', 'H', 'I' },
            { 'J', 'K', 'L' },
            { 'M', 'N', 'O' },
            { 'P', 'R', 'S' },
            { 'T', 'U', 'V' },
            { 'W', 'X', 'Y' } };


    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter seven digit(except 0 and 1):");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        check = number;
        for (; number != 0; number /= 10)
        {
            q = number % 10;
            che[q] = 1;
        }
        if (che[1] != 1 && che[0] != 1) break;
    }
    number = check;

    for (i = 6; number == 0; i--)
    {
        r = number % 10;
        if (r == 2){ word2[i] = 0; }
        if (r == 3){ word2[i] = 1; }
        if (r == 4){ word2[i] = 2; }
        if (r == 5){ word2[i] = 3; }
        if (r == 6){ word2[i] = 4; }
        if (r == 7){ word2[i] = 5; }
        if (r == 8){ word2[i] = 6; }
        if (r == 9){ word2[i] = 7; }
        number /= 10;
    }

    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++){

        for (b = 0; b < 3; b++){

            for (c = 0; c < 3; c++){

                for (d = 0; d < 3; d++){

                    for (e = 0; e < 3; e++){

                        for (f = 0; f < 3; f++){

                            for (g = 0; g < 3; g++){
                                printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c ",word1[word2[0]][a], word1[word2[1]][b], word1[word2[2]][c], word1[word2[3]][d], word1[word2[4]][e], word1[word2[5]][f], word1[word2[6]][g]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: codeSmellHomework++;

Answer (score 2):

Main problem is here:

```
for (i = 6; number == 0; i--)
```

The loop condition is the opposite of the one it should be. You want to keep iterating on the number until you reach `0` (by successively dividing it by 10).

It should be

```
for (i = 6; number != 0; i--)
```

or

```
for (i = 6; i >= 0; i--)
```

In addition mind that

```
    if (r == 2){ word2[i] = 0; }
    if (r == 3){ word2[i] = 1; }
    if (r == 4){ word2[i] = 2; }
    if (r == 5){ word2[i] = 3; }
    if (r == 6){ word2[i] = 4; }
    if (r == 7){ word2[i] = 5; }
    if (r == 8){ word2[i] = 6; }
    if (r == 9){ word2[i] = 7; }
```

is equivalent to

```
 if (r >= 2 && r <= 9)
   word2[i] = r - 2;
```

Comment: So appreciate for your help !!! I really want to raise your reputation but my reputation so low ,SORRY!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this works as you expected:
For some convenience in debugging, I changed some IO format:

Input separated number 2-9 divided by space and end with -1.

The input sequence can be of any length, just end with -1.

For example, input:2 3 4 2 -1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char word1[8][3] = {
    { 'A', 'B', 'C' },
    { 'D', 'E', 'F' },
    { 'G', 'H', 'I' },
    { 'J', 'K', 'L' },
    { 'M', 'N', 'O' },
    { 'P', 'R', 'S' },
    { 'T', 'U', 'V' },
    { 'W', 'X', 'Y' } };

void translate(char * headStr,int * pattern,int pos_to_do)
{
    if(pattern[pos_to_do]<0)
    {
        printf("%s\n",headStr);
        return;
    }
    char str[3][20];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        strcpy(str[i],headStr);
        char str_this[2];
        str_this[0]=word1[ pattern[pos_to_do] ][i];
        str_this[1]='\0';
        strcat(str[i],str_this);
        translate(str[i],pattern,pos_to_do+1);
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    int che[20];

    int number, check,len;

    while (1)
    {
    printf("Enter digits(except 0 and 1):");
    len=0;
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    while(number>=2)
    {
        che[len]=number-2;
        len++;
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }
    che[len]=-1;
    char str_start[]="";
    translate(str_start,che,0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test output:

```
Enter digits(except 0 and 1):2 3 4 -1
ADG
ADH
ADI
AEG
AEH
AEI
AFG
AFH
AFI
BDG
BDH
BDI
BEG
BEH
BEI
BFG
BFH
BFI
CDG
CDH
CDI
CEG
CEH
CEI
CFG
CFH
CFI
Enter digits(except 0 and 1):
```

Comment: you are so professional!!! thanks for your advise,too.I am glad to learn your code.

Comment: Then award him the answer. If you don't people will soon stop helping you (with your homework)